# How to add image onto fixed nav bar using only css and html

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying create a fixed nav bar (only css and html) with an image inside the container for the navbar.  I want the image to be in the top-left corner and the rest of the nav bar items on the top-right side.  I was wondering if this is possible with just using flex?

Thank you!

Below is what I have so far.

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class = "fixed-nav">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/1920px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" alt="">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>

CSS:

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

header{
    margin:0 auto;
}

header img {
    height:70px;
}

.fixed-nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    /* align-items: flex-end; */
    /* justify-content: flex-end; */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 50px; */
    background-color: white;
  }

  nav ul{
    display:flex;
    margin:0;
  }

  nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display:block;
  }
```

Here is a link to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cs5xh8y7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close just change `justify-content:` to  `space-between;`.

Comment: oh wow, I'm sorry I made such a stupid mistake, thanks for the answer.